# Как получить название страны по коду в api restcountries.eu

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

Использую асинхронный вызов async/await для того чтобы получить информацию по стране по api restcountries.eu. Нужно по введенной по инпуту стране, вывести название всех стран которые находятся на границе. Получилось только вывести ссылку данных стран. Дальше что то не получается.

```js
$(() => {
  $('button').on('click', () => {
    let countryName = $('.countryName').val();
    getCountry(countryName);
  })

  let getCountry = async(countryName, code) => {
    let countryUrl = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + countryName;
    let countryCode = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/';
    let response = await fetch(countryUrl);
    console.log(response);
    let country = await response.json();
    let countryInfo = country[0];
    let countryBorders = countryInfo['borders'];
    for (let i in countryBorders) {
      let bordersCode = countryCode + countryBorders[i];
      $('<li>').appendTo('.block2').html(bordersCode);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block1">
    <input type="text" class="countryName">
    <button>Find</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```js
$(() => {
    $('button').on('click', () => {
        let countryName = $('.countryName').val();
        getCountry(countryName);
    })

    let getCountry = async (countryName, code) => {
        let countryUrl = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + countryName;
        let countryCode = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/';
        let response = await fetch(countryUrl);
        console.log(response);
        let country = await response.json();
        console.log(country)
        let countryInfo = country[0];
        let countryBorders = countryInfo['borders'];
        for (let i of countryBorders) {
            await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${i}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    $('<li>').appendTo('.block2').html(res.name);
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Если что-либо не понятно - пишите мне в дискорд: Webfox#9868